# Will Require revert storage changes made in a separate contract in the same transaction - Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I'm new to solidity (and coding in general) so please forgive me if this is a stupid question! I'm trying to understand the scope of the require statement across multiple contracts. I want to design a master contract that a user can set an allowance for that then interacts with several other subcontracts that costs a custom ERC20 token to interact with. The idea is that the user only needs to authorize the master contract that manages their tokens and makes sure that they are transferred to the other contracts for payment when interacted with it, rather than have to get the user to set an allowance for all the other contracts individually.

Say for example we have two contracts, contract A is the master (in this scenario the user has already set the correct allowance), and contract B, the contract that the user wants to interact with. The user calls the function in contract A which checks that they have the required amount of tokens to use the function in b before execution. if everything checks out on the finance side, contract A calls the function in contract B which also needs to check certain variables to proceed.  Providing everything checks out, B adds the user to a mapping and returns, then A executes the transferfrom function.  (I hope this all makes sense);

Could the user change the allowance to zero at some point during call_b's execution in a way that passed the first two require statements but fails when transferfrom executes and if that did happen would a require fail in A revert the storage changes made in B as a result?

or

the other option I have considered is transferring the user's tokes immediately after passing the financial checks and relying on the require statement around  B.f(msg.sender)  to revert the transfer if it fails. (if continue get set to false)

or

is this all really dumb and there is much a better way to proceed.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "Contract_B.sol";
import "Token.sol";

contract Contract_A{

  Contract_B public contract_B;
  Token public token;

   constructor(Contract_B _contract_B, Token _token){
      contract_B =  Contract_B(_contract_B);
      token = Token(_token);
       
    }

    function call_b() public returns(bool){
      //financial checks - the cost against balance and allowance
      uint costToUse = b.costToUse;
      require(token.balanceOf(address(msg.sender)) >= costToUse ,"You don't have enough!");
      require(token.allowance(address(msg.sender), address(this)) >= costToUse , "Allowance to 
      low");

      //Would transerfrom be better here?.Would (require b.f(msg.sender)) revert a transfer.

      //effects - set values  
      require(b.f(msg.sender), "failed!");

      require(token.transferFrom(address(msg.sender), address(this), costToUse ), "Transfer 
      Error");
    }

}

contract Contract_B{
  
  // insstance of master contract for security check
  Contract_A public contract_A;
  
  bool public continue;
  uint public costToUse;
  uint public userCount;
  mapping(uint => address) users;
  
  constructor(Contract_A _contract_A, uint _costToUse){
    contract_A = new(_contract_A); 
    costToUse = _costToUse;
    continue = true;
  }

  modifier onlyA(){
      require(msg.sender == contract_A, "not contract A!");  
    _;
  }
  
  function f(address _user) public onlyA() returns (bool){
    require(continue , "Can not continue");
    users[userCount] = _user;
    userCount++;
    return true;
  }
   
  function setContinue(bool _continue) public onlyA() returns(bool){
      continue= _continue;
      return true;
  }


}
```

Comment: does this answer your question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28985/does-revert-require-revert-changes-made-to-other-contracts

Comment: I think so, thanks for that!